# Xubuntu 20.04 LTS Cant Change Login-Screen Resolution (Thinkpad P50)

Tags: nvidia, xubuntu, lightdm, thinkpad, lock-screen

I recently got a ThinkpadP50 with a fresh Xubuntu 20.04 LTS install

- CPU: Intel i7-6820HQ (8) @ 3.600GHz
- GPU: NVIDIA Quadro M1000M, using nvidia-driver-440

However, I'm having an issue where my lock screen resolution and theme doesn't match or sync to my desktop environment (Xfce). It does this with other distros as well. (ive tried debian and manjaro)

**Also an important note**: when my computer locks from going idle, the lock screen is perfectly fine and there's no issue. It'll match whatever resolution and themes I have set. The problem only occurs when shutting down, locking, restarting, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After many blackscreens of trying different fixes, this workaround seems to resolve the issue kinda [How to adjust display settings for LightDM greeter on 18.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1092699/how-to-adjust-display-settings-for-lightdm-greeter-on-18-04)

I also had to `chmod +x` monitor-config.sh. Without that I ended up stuck in boot

(Right now, the fix works with xubuntu 20.04 LTS, however, I installed manjaro and tried it there and it didnt work. I believe it's a hardware/driver issue.)